# res.download function is not working in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, download

I want to download a file in node.js using express.js framework according to the get request url.

I didn't get an error in this code, but the file is not downloaded, it shows
success message.

Kindly look at following code, can anyone solve this issue?

```html
var express=require("express");
var bodyparser=require("body-parser");
var app=express();
var path=require("path");
app.get("/download/:folder/:file(*)",function(req,res)
{

    var folder=req.params.folder;
    var filename=req.params.file;
    var downloadlocation=path.join(__dirname,folder,filename);
    console.log(downloadlocation);
    res.download(downloadlocation,function(err,success)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log("download failed try again");
        }
        else {
            console.log("download successfully");
        }
    });

});

app.listen(8086,function()
{
    console.log("server is listening on port 8086");
});
```

Comment: `res.download(downloadlocation, filename, function(err,success)`

Comment: Are you sure that it is not downloaded. The given code works fine here.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone the signature is `res.download(path [, filename] [, options] [, fn])` so  `filename` is optional. And because of the `downloadlocation=path.join(__dirname,folder,filename)` it would not make any difference here.

Comment: It is not working here

Comment: Can you try hard code a file url path and test whether it works?

Comment: @demodevelopers does the browser show any error in the console of the developer tools? What does the network tab show if you open that url, which status code?

Comment: @t.niese I am using postman to send the request..Postman got the image as response.but file is not downloaded

Comment: @demodevelopers Postman is a tool to debug http request, not to download files. Why do you expect that is would trigger a download? The `download` function, will add a header to the response that tells the client that a download is desired/expected. Postman will list this header in the header section, but it won't download the file. This would be really annoying for debugging.

Comment: Thanks Now I used browser It's working fine......